# Firebase security rules : How can I use dashes or hyphen in paths?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I can't find a way to use hyphens or dashes in the path of my Firestore security rules.  I'm getting this error message : "Unexpected '-'"

It works only in the online rules editor/simulator, but I'm getting the error when trying to deploy the .rules file using the Firebase CLI (firebase deploy --only firestore:rules).

I tried using single quotes around the hypenated collection name (the path).  I can't find anything on internet about this issue.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Match any document in the 'oversea-users' collection
    match /oversea-users/{oversea-user} {
      allow read: ... condition ...;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found my error was only in the "catch" object name, not in the path. Must use overseaUsers instead of oversea-user between the {}.

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Match any document in the 'overseaUsers' collection
    match /oversea-users/{overseaUsers} {
        allow read: ... condition ...;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That thing in the curly braces is called a "wildcard".