# Unable to access field that has hyphen in it

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am struggling to write a firebase rule that is checking the user id that is stored in a document. Hardcoding a given value as a string works

```
allow write: if request.auth.uid == 'user-id-hardcoded';
```

,however I am unable to find a way to dynamically address it. I am left with the impression it's due to the hyphen in the document field after checking this question - [Firebase security rules : How can I use dashes or hyphen in paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660266/firebase-security-rules-how-can-i-use-dashes-or-hyphen-in-paths). I also tried to substitute user-id with userId to no avail.

```
allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.user-id;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your field name in document contains a hyphen then use the brackets notation instead:

```
allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data["user-id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked this link, it looks like the hyphen will be detected start or end of a structural component.

[FirebaseVisionDocumentText.RecognizedBreak](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/document/FirebaseVisionDocumentText.RecognizedBreak)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey, Frederic, you're correct. I was suspecting something like it.